# JSON.NET custom serialization of properties

Tags: json, json.net, serialization

I have a class looks like below

```
public class Sample { 
    public string schema { get; set; } 
    public string version { get; set; } 
}
```

Output I am looking for is

```
{
    $schema : "some schema", 
    version : "1.1.1.1.1" 
}
```

I used below code to serialize the

```cs
public class SchemaSerializer : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var schema = value as string;
        writer.WriteStartObject();
        writer.WritePropertyName("$schema");
        serializer.Serialize(writer, schema);
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject jsonObject = JObject.Load(reader);
        var properties = jsonObject.Properties().ToList();
        return new Schema
        {
            SchemaName = properties[0].Name.Replace("$", ""),
            Value = (string)properties[0].Value
        };
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(Schema).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }
}
```

However this produces output below

```
{
   schema : {$schema : "some schema" } , 
   version : "1.1.1.1.1"
}
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JsonProperty with string property name solve this problem

```
  [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "$schema")]
public string Schema { get; set; }
```